# Backgroundimage - Changing

Tags: javascript, html, background-image

i want to change the backgroundimage on my homepage every time you refresh. 
How can I make that? 
I think it´s possible with jquery but I don´t know exaktly.

Thank you for any help or comment on this subject.

Comment: Do you want your new background to be an random background, want it to follow a certain order or do your want it to be related to the loaded link?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know "HOW TO", but I have found the following link:

http://www.9lessons.info/2011/03/background-image-change-on-refresh-with.html